# Using useEffect with Axios & Await

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, use-effect

I'm having an issue getting my "topic" state to update when using Axios. At first I thought useEffect wasn't being called but when I put a simple `useEffect(() => setTopic("Test"))` in it worked fine. So somehow I believe the await is messing me up.

**The issue:** When the useEffect below is called the page requires a refresh to show the updated state.

**What can I do to update the state correctly and show it without a page refresh?**

```
useEffect(async () => {
const result = await axios({
method: "GET",
withCredentials: true,
url: "http://localhost:4000/userData",
}).then((res) => {
setTopic(res.data.topic);
});
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback function inside a useEffect can't be **async**

What you can do rather is to call an **async** function from within **useEffect** which will do the things for you. Here is an example:

```
const fetchUserData = async () => {
    const result = await axios({
        method: "GET",
        withCredentials: true,
        url: "http://localhost:4000/userData",
    }).then((res) => {
        setTopic(res.data.topic);
    });
};    

useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData();
}, [])
```

Comment: This works but it still does not update state when useEffect is called. I still have to refresh.

Comment: It can't happen. Share a code sandbox example of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
async function runThis() {
  const result = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true, 
    url: "http://localhost:4000/userData",
 }).then((res) => {
  setTopic(res.data.topic);
 }); 
}

useEffect(
   runThis();
}, [])
```

Comment: This works but it still does not update state when useEffect is called. I still have to refresh.

Comment: Can you see the axios response? e.g. console.log(res.data.topic)

Comment: interestingly enough, the console.log is blank until I refresh as well. On refresh everything updates accordingly

Comment: Are you using create react app or nextjs? You should also note that promises take time to resolve.